# Dispatch and setState not working together, but are on their own

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a DatePicker component, when I click on a new date it should set the change the date in the redux store, and also visibly UX-wise.

I'll put my code down below, for some reason in the `handleChange` function, with both the `setState` and the `this.props.addFitler` there firing off, the redux store updates correctly but the UX doesn't. 
However if I comment out the `this.props.addFilter` dispatch function, the UX update correctly (and obviously the store doesn't).

Why aren't both of these working together? I've tried changing the order in which they're called, extracting each into another function, using mapDispatchToProps instead of calling the action creator directly, all to no avail.

DatePicker.js:

```
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';

class DatePick extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      date: moment()
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(date) {
    const { dashboardName } = this.props;
    const { name } = this.props.column;
    this.props.addFilter(date, dashboardName, name);
    this.setState({date});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{display: 'inline-block', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>
        <DatePicker
          dateFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
          selected={this.state.date}
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapActionToProps = {
  addFilter
};

export default connect(null, mapActionToProps)(DatePick);
```

The 'date' parameter that comes through in the handleChange function is a moment object just like the one used to set initialState, so that isn't the issue.

Additional info: If I console log before and after `setState()` it logs the initial state both times.

Has anyone ran into this problem or have any ideas? If you need to see my redux I can update the post with more code but I don't think that's the problem as it updates the store fine.

Comment: use callback method, try this: `this.setState({date}, () => {
 this.props.addFilter(date, dashboardName, name);
});`

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately didn't work. set the store but not ux

Comment: which part is not working, ui or store update ?

Comment: The store is updating (as always) but the ux date isn't changing. I tried swapping around the callback too

Comment: check the console is it throwing any error ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, action creator calling is doing some synchronous operation and the whole UI thread is locked until it finishes whatever it's doing. Hence we can delay the call a little bit with the help of setTimeout and everything will go as expected

Comment: you should post related code too, that will help some users to understand the implementation better.

Comment: Old problem but once the `setTimeout` finishes the ux gets reset

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `setTimeout` would be a good solution as suggested in the previous answer. We can not determine the actual time taken by the action creator (as it may contain an asynchronous call such as API call). This would again lead to the original problem of setState rendering going missing. Again setting a long timeout would be bad practice. Your application will have an unnecessary delay.

### Solution

1. **A possible solution would be to use the callback method of `setState` to fire the action creator.**

   ```
   handleChange(date) {
       const { dashboardName } = this.props;
       const { name } = this.props.column;
       this.setState({date}, () => { 
           this.props.addFilter(date, dashboardName, name); 
       });
   }
   ```

   In this case the action creator will be fired after the `setState` is finished rendering.
2. **Other solution is to use react lifecycle method to run `setState` when new props are received.**
   This way the `setState` is fired after the action creator has returned the props and changed the state.

   ```
   componentWillRecieveProps (nextProps) {
       // check the related prop is changed
       // setState
   }
   ```

   But with react 17 this method will be deprecated soon. The new stable replacement for it is the following. https://hackernoon.com/problematic-react-lifecycle-methods-are-going-away-in-react-17-4216acc7d58b

   ```
   static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
       // check the related prop is changed
       // setState
   }
   ```